# How to get invisible page source in appium?

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium, appium-desktop

When i swipe to next page and get `page_source` , I can't get last `page_source` content

That is I only can get current visible page_source

But I want to scrape lots of page, get only visible page source is low efficient

Any way to get invisible outside page_source in appium? I use python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to understand what page would you like to catch - native or webview?
Try to get a page source for debugging - https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/ .

Maybe you need to switch a context to get a page source?

Here how I implemented context switching.

1. In some Page Object files I keep Android (or iOS) contexts.

   ```
    ANDROID_CONTEXTS = {
        'webview': 'WEBVIEW_ru.myapp',
        'native': 'NATIVE_APP'
    }
   ```
2. In some tests I switch context from Native to Webview.

   ```
    @allure.link(url='https://jira.project.tech/browse/TEST-1', name='TEST-1 - Fill payment form')
    @allure.title('Fill payment form')
    def test_card_standard_1_month(appdriver):

        Paywall(appdriver).press_one_month_button()
        PaymentsPage(appdriver).select_card_payment()
        PaymentsPage(appdriver).press_payment_button()


        appdriver.switch_to.context(ANDROID_CONTEXTS['webview'])
        Payform(appdriver).fill_and_submit_payoform()

        appdriver.switch_to.context(ANDROID_CONTEXTS['native'])

        assert SuccessPayment(appdriver).get_successful_payment_title_text() == 'Your subscription is successful!'
   ```

You can check all available contexts in your app. More info here -> http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/